# Is this possible to add many relations between two models? Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations, model-associations, ruby-on-rails-7

I am working with a database like this :[link to db UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCYuo.png)

All my models are link to User with *'belongs_to'* (User have *'has_many'*).

My Contact and Society models are link to the Project one by a *'has_many: through:'*.

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
   validates_presence_of :name, :firstname, :job, :email, :phone

   has_many :projects
   has_many :societies, through: :projects

   belongs_to :user
end

class Society < ApplicationRecord
   has_one_attached :logo

   has_many :projects
   has_many :contacts, through: :projects
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

   belongs_to :user


end

class Project < ApplicationRecord

   validates_presence_of :name, :value, :description
   belongs_to :society
   belongs_to :contact
   belongs_to :user

end
```

So when I create a project I can associate a contact and a society to this project.
The thing is that I want to be able to associate a contact directly when i create a society.
The problem is that I can't access "contact.societies" and "society.contacts" until a project isn't created

My question is, is this possible to add a **many to many** relation between Contact and Society so that I could be able to associate a society and a contact without created a projet ?
Or maybe should I change the association 'has_many: through:' ?

I'm waiting your answers,

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Without source code it's hard to know what your issue is, but taking a flying guess, check out the [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) feature, if that doesn't help you then please edit your question to include some source code, show your model associations, and the code you're trying to run to create your project.

Comment: Ok i gonna try this before editing my question.
For accepts_nested_attributes_for, should I add contact_id for society in database ? (and society_id for contact ? )

Comment: I see on the website that is for One-to-One or One-to-Many, or my Society and Contact are link by a has_many: through: so a Many-to-Many